# Does it make sense to use unit test frameworks for integration tests?

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing, automated-tests

Unit tests are meant to test individual pieces of code (usually single methods) in an automated fashion. Unit test frameworks such as NUnit or MSTest are designed to support these kinds of tests.

However, there is nothing to keep you from calling multiple methods in sequence (altering some state with each method) and verifying the result. This would be an integration test. Example pseudocode:

```
var f = new Folder("C:\\");
var f2 = f.CreateSubfolder("test");
Assert.Exists(f2.Path)

var file = f2.CreateFile("abc.txt");
Assert.Exists(file.Path)

f2.Delete();
Assert.NotExists(f2);
```

The intention here is to test not the individual methods but the result of a sequence of method calls that alter some common state. Using the filesystem might not be the best example of automated tests, but the concept is common enough to be easily understood.

Is it acceptable to write integration tests in this manner? What are the advantages and disadvantages of such an approach?

Comment: If you're suggesting your test code lives inline with your real code, then that's probably not a good idea...

Comment: Absolutely not. A method such as the above would be a [Test] method just like any unit test. Just that it isn't actually a unit test.

Comment: Ah, I see.  But in that case, why isn't the sequence of calls already wrapped into a class/method/etc.?  That way, you'd avoid the duplication of the sequential code.

Comment: I don't understand where you're seeing duplication. The above code is an example of a test method.

Comment: What I mean is, presumably you already have some "real" code that's doing "var f = ...; var f2 = ...;" (i.e. some code that integrates a set of modules), and you want to test that.  The code in your question implies that you're now duplicating that sequence of calls in your test code.

Comment: Maybe, or maybe not. However such tests are desirable because like unit tests, they can be run and re-run, serving as regression tests at a higher level of abstraction. Also, certain methods (such as Delete()) do not return a result, so you can't write a unit test to ensure it works.

Comment: yes it is acceptable to write integration tests using unit test frameworks. There aren't any general purpose integration test frameworks anyway - because the unit test frameworks serve just fine.

Comment: If you do this, you probably want to somehow distinguish between your unit tests and your integration tests. E.g. you might want to fail a build because of a failed unit test, but not because of a failed integration test because that could fail because of an external API call.